# Getting error while sending multicast message in xmpp - No S2S connection

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

i am getting this error while sending message.

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="multicast.Debian-85-jessie-64-minimal" to="24@debian-85-jessie-64-minimal/5943937852686817861326" type="error">
<addresses xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/address">
    <address type="to" jid="25@Debian-85-jessie-64-minimal" />
</addresses>
<body>37.420996###-122.223887###24</body>
<error code="503" type="cancel">
    <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" />
    <text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">No s2s connection found</text>
</error>
```

what could be the reason.

below is the configuration i set for this in ejabbered.yml file

```
host_config:
 "Debian-85-jessie-64-minimal":
   access:
     c2s:
       - allow: all
       - deny
     register:
       - allow: all
       - deny

    multicast:
      - allow: all


mod_multicast:
    host: "debian-85-jessie-64-minimal"
access: multicast
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?